# Order fields when serializing

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am xml serializing an object and I cannot seem to change the order in which the fields are serialized.

I.e.

```
public class foo{
string a {get;set;}
string b {get;set;}
}
```

Comes out as (pseudocode)

```
<foo b="world" a="hello" />
```

When I need

```
<foo a="hello" b="world" />
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: in xml, both output are equivalent. Don't your consuming program is xml compliant ? Anyways, I don't think it's possible without a custom serialization process. It is for elements with the [Order property of XmlElementAttribute class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.order.aspx), and there is no equivalent for attributes

Comment: @SteveB Unfortunately not, the remote program throws an exception if the order is incorrect. Its out of my hands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cannot achieve this via [decorating the class with XML attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (which you cannot do if you *require* XML attributes instead of XML elements as output), you may need to implement `IXmlSerializable` yourself, mentioned briefly here:

[custom xml serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109827/custom-xml-serialization)

And here:

[Proper way to implement IXmlSerializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable)