# Deserialize XML into Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have some XML;

```
<data>
  <name1>James</name1>
  <name2>John</name2>
  etc..
</data>
```

The name1, name2, etc could be anything, i want to be able to get this xml into a dictionary ideally, is this possible using the built in .net serialisation?

Thanks,
James.

EDIT: Ideally i dont want to use linq. Is it possible to serialise the whole element array to a string? So i'd end up with a string object 'Data' that contained all the child element tags and data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, but you can use *Linq-to-Xml* to do so:

```
XDocument.Load([file path, stream, whatever]).Descendants("data").Descendants()
    .ToDictionary(element => element.Name, element => element.Value)
```

**UPDATE:**
As OP said in his edit, if there's no way to use Linq-to-Xml, then you¡ll need to customize XML serialization implementing `IXmlSerializable` (you might want to check this other Q&A: [custom xml serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109827/custom-xml-serialization) ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to XML with method `ToDictionary()`;