# c# deserialize xml with dynamic tag names

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have a dynamic XML structure which is looks like this:

```
<RES>
<A>value 1</A>
<B>value 2</B>    
<C>value 3</C>
</RES>
```

My question is how can I parse it to Dictionary<string, string> object?

I tried this but it is no working:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "RES")]
public Dictionary<string, string> result { get; set; }
```

Could you please help me on it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize XML into Dictionary<string, string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210059/deserialize-xml-into-dictionarystring-string)

Comment: I read that article but maybe I haven't got too much experience in this level. So I have to implement IXmlSerializable  interface and use it instead of XmlElement ?

Comment: Or use linq to xml as shown.

Comment: I have choose this way to implement what I need: https://gist.github.com/refractalize/1751260 It is working fine for me. Thank you all of you for your help.

Comment: @Zaosz - that gist looks quite clean and simple.  Do you want to make an answer yourself?  If not this could be closed as a duplicate of [Deserialize XML into Dictionary<string, string>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9210059/3744182) (for loading with Linq-to-XML then using `ToDictionary()` plus [Deserialize XML with XmlSerializer where XmlElement names differ but have same content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45766597/3744182) (for the `[XmlAnyElement] public XElement[] XElements { ... }` surrogate property trick).

Comment: Thank you! it is working fine.